# What's wrong with this Active Record line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is throwing me a long error about missing a tIDENTIFIER. Can't seem to see anything wrong with it

```
      <%= link_to_if(customer.try(:company_id).try(:blank?), "Company: #{@company.find(customer[:company_id].name}", { controller => 'companies', action => 'show', id => customer.company_id }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= link_to_if(customer.try(:company_id).try(:blank?), "Company: #{@company.find(customer[:company_id]).name}", { controller => 'companies', action => 'show', id => customer.company_id }) %>
```

Missing bracket here  @company.find(customer[:company_id].name